# regular expression - how to connect two groups to one value?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have got problems with trolls once again.
There is situation something like that:

```
<?php 
    [...]
    $string="IchigoKurosaki FirstRandomTroll NatsuDragneel SecondRandomTroll NarutoUzumaki TrollMaster";
    //[do some magic here]
    //$outputArray = {
        [1] => "FirstRandomTroll SecondRandomTroll",
        [2] => "TrollMaster"
    }
?>
```

I want to use preg_match to catch in groups trolls. I have got 3 groups:

```
(firstRandomTroll), (secondRandomTroll), and (TrollMaster)
```

which are saved to `$output` as

```
[1] => "first...", [2]=> "second...", and [3]="TrollMaster".
```

Is this possible to connect [1] and [2] to one value using only one regular expression and nothing more?

Comment: Why don't you just write your `string` and desired `output` ?

Comment: I don't see the logic behind connecting [1] and [2]. Why do you connect those and not [3] ? What if there are more trolls in the $string ?

Comment: @Theox: It is because trolls live as a couple.

Comment: Just search for each troll individually, add to array as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a regex to capture every troll in the string :

```
$string="IchigoKurosaki FirstRandomTroll NatsuDragneel SecondRandomTroll NarutoUzumaki TrollMaster";

preg_match_all("([a-zA-Z]*Troll[a-zA-Z]*)", $string, $array);

print_r($array);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => FirstRandomTroll
            [1] => SecondRandomTroll
            [2] => TrollMaster
        )
)
```

The trolls are now isolated (that's for the better, right ?)

Now you can perform operations on the elements of the array to regroup them (sounds like a bad idea, it's trolls we are talking about ...). Just be careful with the structure of this array.

Now if you really, really want to capture two trolls at once, I don't think it's possible with one regex. You could rewrite it to have two capturing groups, but that's will not output two trolls in one string right away ...